# SQL Native Client not Installed alert

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, powerbuilder

We have bunch of PowerBuilder executable desktop applications and we're migrating them to Windows 10.  When launching the executables on Windows 10 that connect to SQL Server 2008R2 in the backend we get the following message.

I tried placing sql DLLs found in Windows 7 system32 folder (on machine it works) into Windows 10 system32 folder but did not work.

Any ideas?  Do I have to install a SQL native client on the Windows 10 workstations?

[SQL Native Client not installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL7zR.png)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 R2 is not supported on Windows 10.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2681562

I don't have Windows 10 to test it, but I imagine you can install a supported version of SQL Server and it will connect to older version just fine.

*** Also, you cannot just copy the SQL DLL's to a different machine.  You need to update the ODBC registry entries so Windows knows what drivers are installed and where to find them.